# Audio recording using PortAudio: Pa_GetStreamReadAvailable not work?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, real-time, portaudio

I make realtime data processing application (spectrum analyzer using fftw3 lib) using C and Linux. My incoming data is currently taken from h/w audio line input. I use PortAudio libs to talk to h/w. (I *do not* use PortAudio's *callbacks* currently). I select Portaudio, due to many audio-recording examples exist for it. RtAudio, while may offer lower latencies, unfortunately written on CPP, not C (so i have multiple portability troubles). (Should i try other wrapper? Is there direct way to catch sound buffer, with examples?).

I have fine working setup unless DFT calculations take more time than enough for filling audio buffer with new data. So data stays and accumulates somewhere in system, and delay between audio input and picture occurs and increases. In spectrum analysis, there is not possible to "throw away" piece of data. So only i can do is warn the user about low CPU horsepower. But here i have problem.

There is **Pa_GetStreamReadAvailable** function exist to show how many unreaded data available. But it is not working at all for me. I prepare simple example, mostly based on file [www.kfr.co.il/files/speed_photo/complete.c](http://www.kfr.co.il/files/speed_photo/complete.c)

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/parport.h>
#include <linux/ppdev.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <portaudio.h>

/* #define SAMPLE_RATE  (17932) // Test failure to open with this value. */
#define SAMPLE_RATE  (44100)
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER (1024)
#define NUM_SECONDS     (5)
#define NUM_CHANNELS    (2)
/* #define DITHER_FLAG     (paDitherOff)  */
#define DITHER_FLAG     (0) /**/

/* Select sample format. */
#if 1
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paFloat32
typedef float SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0.0f)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%.8f"
#elif 1
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paInt16
typedef short SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%d"
#elif 0
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paInt8
typedef char SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%d"
#else
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paUInt8
typedef unsigned char SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (128)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%d"
#endif

int running = 1;

void signalHandler(int sig)
{
   running = 0;
}


/*******************************************************************/
int main(void);
int main(void)
{
    printf("Initializing PortAudio...\n");
    PaStreamParameters inputParameters, outputParameters;
    PaStream *stream;
    PaError err;
    SAMPLE *recordedSamples;
    int i;
    int maxFrames;
    int numSamples;
    int numBytes;
    SAMPLE max, average, val;

    // Set ctrl-c handler
    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);

    //totalFrames = NUM_SECONDS * SAMPLE_RATE; /* Record for a few seconds. */
    maxFrames = SAMPLE_RATE*1;
    numSamples = maxFrames * NUM_CHANNELS;

    numBytes = numSamples * sizeof(SAMPLE);
    recordedSamples = (SAMPLE *) malloc( numBytes );
    if( recordedSamples == NULL )
    {
        printf("Could not allocate record array.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for( i=0; i<numSamples; i++ ) recordedSamples[i] = 0;

    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    inputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice(); /* default input device */
    if (inputParameters.device == paNoDevice) {
      fprintf(stderr,"Error: No default input device.\n");
      goto error;
    }
    inputParameters.channelCount = NUM_CHANNELS;
    inputParameters.sampleFormat = PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
    inputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( inputParameters.device )->defaultLowInputLatency;
    inputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

    /* Record some audio. -------------------------------------------- */
    err = Pa_OpenStream(
              &stream,
              &inputParameters,
              NULL,                  /* &outputParameters, */
              SAMPLE_RATE,
              FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
              paClipOff,      /* we won't output out of range samples so don't bother clipping them */
              NULL, /* no callback, use blocking API */
              NULL ); /* no callback, so no callback userData */
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    printf("Starting!\n\n");

    printf("Numbers should increasing:\n");

    err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    Pa_ReadStream(stream, recordedSamples, maxFrames);
    i = 1;
    while (i<8)
    {
        long toRead = Pa_GetStreamReadAvailable(stream);
        printf("%ld %d\n", toRead, maxFrames);
        if (toRead > maxFrames)
            toRead = maxFrames;
        err = Pa_ReadStream(stream, recordedSamples, toRead);
        if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

        //  Here is place for heavy calculations,
        // they can be longer than time needed for filling one buffer.
        // (So data, awaiting for processing, should be (and really is)
        // accumulated somewhere in system/OS buffer.)
        //  Emulate big delays:
        usleep(i*1000000);
        i++;
    }

    printf("Stopping PortAudio...\n");
    err = Pa_CloseStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    free( recordedSamples );

    Pa_Terminate();
    return 0;

error:
    Pa_Terminate();
    fprintf( stderr, "An error occured while using the portaudio stream\n" );
    fprintf( stderr, "Error number: %d\n", err );
    fprintf( stderr, "Error message: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText( err ) );
    return -1;
}
```

I expect increasing numbers in printout, but my results are clearly wrong:

```
598 44100
3071 44100
3071 44100
3071 44100
3071 44100
3071 44100
3071 44100
```

Using 'Pa_OpenDefaultStream' in place of 'Pa_OpenStream' gives other wrong numbers (8191).
Where am i wrong?

Or it is bug in PA, but to be sure, i prefer to ask first, before file a bugreport.
Thanks.

P.S. Regression of PA libs to previous version (for tests) is not possible, i can't compile this example in modern Ubuntu with it.

Comment: Try increasing inputParameters.suggestedLatency. you have specified low latency, which is likely to be shorter than 3071 samples. In other words, you have not asked PA to create a large enough intermediate buffer. You will *always* have to collect the data before PA's buffer overflows. There is no guarantee that PA supports a 1 second buffer either.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me that there is a bug here (Apart from your doing a FFT that takes too long on your box).

Usually the audio subsystem has a small number of buffers (Looks like 3 in your case 3072 is 3 * 1024 which you set as FRAMES_PER_BUFFER, 2 is another common value) and if you fail to keep up it simply discards data from the least recently filled buffer, there is no ever growing buffer of audio.

It is your responsibility to copy the data out of those buffers in time and to buffer in ram or on disk of that is what you need to do for your application.

I am somewhat surprised that a modern machine has any trouble with a 1024 point FFT at audio rate.

Regards, Dan.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code as a starting point but my stream needs to stay open.  I was able to get this working but you would need to message your FFT processing on a different thread, possibly using RingBuffer or another mechanism as if you increase the thread sleep code, it will throw a Input Underrun error.

```
while( ( err = Pa_IsStreamActive( stream ) ) == 1 )
{
    long toRead = Pa_GetStreamReadAvailable(stream);
    
    if (toRead > FRAMES_PER_BUFFER) toRead = FRAMES_PER_BUFFER;

    if (toRead == FRAMES_PER_BUFFER) {
    
        printf("available: %ld frames_per_buffer: %d\n", toRead, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);
        
        // You may get underruns or overruns if the output is not primed by PortAudio.
        err = Pa_ReadStream( stream, recordedSamples, toRead );
        if(err) goto xrun;
    }

    Pa_Sleep(10);
}


available: 1024 frames_per_buffer: 1024
available: 1024 frames_per_buffer: 1024
available: 1024 frames_per_buffer: 1024
available: 1024 frames_per_buffer: 1024
available: 1024 frames_per_buffer: 1024
available: 1024 frames_per_buffer: 1024
available: 1024 frames_per_buffer: 1024
available: 1024 frames_per_buffer: 1024
available: 1024 frames_per_buffer: 1024
available: 1024 frames_per_buffer: 1024
available: 1024 frames_per_buffer: 1024
available: 1024 frames_per_buffer: 1024
```